# PHP - Convert integer variable value to decimal

Tags: php, variables

I have a variable `fl_duration` which takes integer value 1,2,3. I am looking to create a new variable 'decimal' which will return the value as a decimal number i.e. 0.1 , 0.2, 0.3.

```
$decimal = get_field('fl_duration');
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: For 10+ values? 0.10 or 1.0 ??

Comment: it's only 1,2,3 - no other values, so I shouldnt worry about that

Comment: What about dividing by ten? like `function dec($flDur) {return $flDur/10;}; $decimal = dec($fl_duration);`

Comment: Division by 10 !

Comment: Or multiply by `0.1`.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried and where you are stuck?

Comment: `$decimal=(float)preg_replace("/^/", "0.", $fl_duration);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP will convert it to an float itself so you can just do it by basic math.

```
<?php

$int = 1;
$dec = $int / 10;
var_dump($int);
var_dump($dec);
```

Output:

> int(1)
>
> float(0.1)

Answer (score 1):

How about `number_format()`, is this what you are looking for?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

```
$decimal = number_format( 1, 2); //will give you string(4) "1.00"
```

Comment: If you are unsure, you need to ask it in the comments section of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like this:

```
$int = 1;
$dec = (float) "0.$int";
// or
$dec = (double) "0.$int";
var_dump($dec);
```

Output:

> float(0.1)